# Is this supposed to work this way?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have this code up on my server [here](http://smplsite.com/sandbox2/process.asmx) (Yes I known ASMX is a bad idea but WCF doesn't work at all for some reason):

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="Test" %>

using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://smplsite.com/smplAccess")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class Test : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    State s;

    public Test()
    {
        s = (Session["foo"] ?? (Session["foo"] = new State())) as State ;
    }

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public void Set(int j) { i=j; }

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public int Get() { return i; }
}

class State
{
    public int i = 5;
}
```

when I run the folloing code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ser = new ServiceReference1.TestSoapClient();

        Console.WriteLine(ser.Get());
        ser.Set(3);
        Console.WriteLine(ser.Get());
    }
}
```

I expect to get back:

```
5
3
```

but I got back

```
5
5
```

### My Solution

1. Usee `wsdl.exe` to generate a proxy class
2. Add references as needed to get it to compile
3. Use [Martin's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808168/is-this-supposed-to-work-this-way/808219#808219) solution

---

[This Seems related](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.enablesession.aspx)

Edit: Added State object.

Comment: I would strongly suggest you try to get a WCF "Hello, world" service working, then try to figure out why your WCF version of this "didn't work at all". This would be a bad reason to stick yourself with ASMX.

Comment: @John: WCF hello world works on my system. Trying the same code on my server fails and talks with tech support indicated that WCF is officially disallowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Web services are stateless, so they do not store their state between multiple calls. Everytime you call a method, a new instance of the service will be created and its members will have the default values again.

What you can do, is to enable session state (as you have done) and store your state in the ASP.NET session.

Something like this:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public void Set(int j) { Session["i"] = j; }

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public int Get() { return Session["i"] == null ? 5 : (int)Session["i"]; }
```

This was what is required on the server side. But you also have to take care on the client side:

Since an ASP.NET session is identified by a cookie, you have to make sure that you are passing the same cookie to the server with every web method call. To do so, you have to instantiate a CookieContainer and assign it to the web service proxy instance:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ser = new ServiceReference1.TestSoapClient();
    ser.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: there is no CookieContainer on the type... Hmm.

Comment: this looks related :b http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/10/interoperability-gotcha-visual-studio.html

Comment: If you add a "Web Reference", then you should see the CookieContainer property.

Comment: trying to add a web reference just hangs at step 4 from the above blog. It just sits there forever with the "waiting" bar running.

Comment: I got around this by using WSDL.exe and adding a few System.Web.* references.

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn on sessions.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```

Comment: Check configuration/system.web/sessionState  in your web.config for the asmx.  It can override session on your web method if it is turned to "off".

Comment: I don't even have a web.config

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like its not persisting class state between session method calls - probably a new object is being called each time. I'm actually not sure that you can rely on getting the same object instance each time you call the service. Joshua's answer is correct, but you'll also need to write code to persist your service's internal field into that session.

Comment: @John: You _can_ rely on _never_ getting the same instance twice. You get a new instance for each request!

Comment: @John Yeah, that's what I figured. I was way, way to lazy to go check and thus wanted to hedge my bet a litte. :)